# Firebase JS - authenticate user in all sub domains

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, token, subdomain

My idea is to have a modal login in all my apps ***app1.myapp.com***, ***app2.myapp.com***.

If I log on ***app1.myapp.com***, i'm not authenticated in *app2.myapp.com*.

I'm trying to use ***[signInWithCustomToken()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth)***.

There are 3 ways to auth:

1. login with password & email

   ```
   firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function (result) { 
   //logged in 
   })
   ```
2. Sign in

   ```
   firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).then(function (result) {
   //logged in 
   })
   ```
3. Facebook login

   ```
   firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider())
   ```

With ***onAuthStateChanged*** i check if user is really logged

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  if (typeof user == 'object' && typeof user.uid != 'string') {
    console.log('no user');
    return false;
  }
  // set Auth Token
});
```

So, I do not understand how create custom token: I try to use *getIdTokenResult* inside event *onAuthStateChanged* like that

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
.then((idTokenResult) => {
    console.log(idTokenResult.token);
    Cookies.set('mpf_tkn', idTokenResult.token, { domain: mycookiedomain });
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

and on ready document I do this

```
var mpf_tkn = Cookies.get('mpf_tkn', { domain: mycookiedomain });
if (mpf_tkn) {
    console.log('signin with custom token');
    firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(mpf_tkn);
}
```

but it returns error!

How can I authenticate a user in all app subdomain?